# How do I convert a binary value to a Redis command?

Tags: redis, rust

I want to call a Redis function with a binary value of `[u8]` using the [`redis-rs`](https://crates.io/crates/redis) crate using the following code:

```rust
let _ : () = redis::cmd("...").arg("...").arg(data).query(&mut con)?;
```

However, it results in this error when `data` is `Vec<u8>`:

```
the trait `redis::ToRedisArgs` is not implemented for `&std::vec::Vec<u8>`
```

And this error when `data` is `[u8]`:

```
the trait `redis::ToRedisArgs` is not implemented for `[u8]`
```

When looking at the documentation for `ToRedisArgs`, there should be one implementation for `Vec<T>` though.

Comment: There's an implementation for either `&[u8]` or `Vec<u8>`, but you apparently tried with `[u8]` and `&Vec<u8>`, so you need to dereference or reference as appropriate.

Comment: You can also trigger a deref coercion by explicitly specifying the argument type as `&[u8]` when passing in a `&Vec<u8>`.

Comment: Thanks &data[..] worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reproducible example of your problem:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data: &std::vec::Vec<u8> = &Vec::new();
    let _ = redis::cmd("...").arg(data);
}
```

Compiling it results in this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&std::vec::Vec<u8>: redis::ToRedisArgs` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:33
  |
3 |   let _ = redis::cmd("...").arg(data);
  |                                 ^^^^ the trait `redis::ToRedisArgs` is not implemented for `&std::vec::Vec<u8>`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <std::vec::Vec<T> as redis::ToRedisArgs>
```

As the error message states, `ToRedisArgs` is implemented for `Vec<T>`, but not `&Vec<T>`. To get around this, you can clone `data` to get a `Vec<u8>`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data: &std::vec::Vec<u8> = &Vec::new();
    let _ = redis::cmd("...").arg(data.clone());
}
```

Or, you can extract a slice from the vector because `ToRedisArgs` is implemented for slices:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data: &std::vec::Vec<u8> = &Vec::new();
    let _ = redis::cmd("...").arg(data.as_slice());
}
```